# updating MySQL without page reload

Tags: javascript, mysql

basically im trying to make the ubiquitous "like button," and update a MySQL table after its clicked without loading the page.  I imagine this would use javascript, but I'm not sure how to access MySQL with javascript.  Please answer for pure javascript only as I dont use JQuery.  Thanks.

Comment: What's your server side language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Ajax](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html) to accomplish this task.

Check [this](http://www.simpletutorials.com/?path=tutorials/javascript/simple_ajax) tutorial too.

Comment: I have provide Ajax tuorial to help you out.

Comment: I wonder who downvoted this and why. Ajax is all you need, very simple. +1

Comment: @Juan, I downvoted before the answer was edited and was simply "You have to use Ajax to accomplish this." with no links.

Comment: I see, I usually prefer to leave a comment explaining why it's a poor answer. I reserve downvoting for answers that are really wrong and I really want to point that out to others, even at the expense of my own reputation. Just my two cent.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax would be the perfect way. You access the "server page e.g. PHP/JSP/ASP" which in turn updates the MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

To access a MySQL database from JavaScript, you'll need to implement a call to a server side script.

For tips on setting up the javascript without jQuery, you might check this guide (and the following pages):
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp